# How to use bedework?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to build an application which requires bedework as the backend calendar server, but am unable to get relevant documentation to set it up. Furthermore, I need to understand the mechanism to use it with android.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about bedework in specific, but the docs are here http://www.bedework.org/bedework/update.do?artcenterkey=36 and you can download what you need here: http://www.bedework.org/bedework/update.do?artcenterkey=2. Once you have it, presumably the JAR file, just drop it in your app and do what you want with it..

Comment: I wish it was that straightforward, but its not. Since bedework is simply calendar database based on information sharing through CalDAV, hence, the front end to the calendar needs to be customized as per need. If there is an already built front end with proper API calls, life would become much easier.